# Change the background color of a menu to show active page using SASS and twig

Tags: css, sass

Ok, so my question's relatively simple and I'm certain I'm super close to solving it, but I just can't see the solution. I'm developping a website using October CMS and I'm using SASS to deal with my various CSS styles. What I'm trying to do here is basically have a menu visually show me on what page by altering the background color. Here's what I have in my SCSS file:

```
.left-menu{

        height: 30px;
        width: 186px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: white;
        line-height: 30px;
        text-align: center;

        .normal {
            background: #f47321;
            background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 21px, #f47321 0);
        }

        .active {
            background: #f68b1f;
            background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 21px, #f68b1f 0);
        }

        &:hover{
            background: #f68b1f;
            background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 21px, #f68b1f 0);
        }
    }
```

And on my web page, I have the following:

```
<a href="/"><div class="{{ (page == 'accueil') ? 'left-menu active' : 'left-menu normal' }} ">ACCUEIL</div></a>
```

I'd like to point out that the twig condition works and, when I'm on the "accueil" page, I end up having the "left-menu active" part displayed in the class attribute and the "left-menu normal" class when I'm on another page.

My problem is that it doesn't work. For some reason, the "active" and "normal" parts don't get picked up. However, the "hover" works perfectly. Anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: In response to joknawe, I did the following modifications to my code (adding the ampersand and getting rid of the "normal" style):

```
.left-menu{

        height: 30px;
        width: 186px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: white;
        line-height: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #f47321;
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 21px, #f47321 0);

        &.active {
            background: #f68b1f;
            background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 21px, #f68b1f 0);
        }

        &:hover{
            background: #f68b1f;
            background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 21px, #f68b1f 0);
        }
    }
```

This gets compiled to the following:

```
.left-menu {
  height: 30px;
  width: 186px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f47321;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 21px, #f47321 0);
}

.left-menu.active  {
  background: #f68b1f;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 21px, #f68b1f 0);
}
```

Then, in the html page, I have the resulting code:

```
<a href="/"><div class="left-menu active ">ACCUEIL</div></a>
```

However, it still doesn't work. All I have is the standard background, the "active" class doesn't seem to get picked up by the browser.

Comment: You might be better off using javascript to determine the active page

Comment: Determining the active page is not the problem. I'm having trouble getting my CSS rule to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add `&` to those selectors: `&.normal` and `&.active` (similar to `&:hover`)

Your current use is treating `.normal` and `.active` as children (applying to any child element of `.left-menu` that has those classes) when you are actually looking for the element to have both the `.left-menu` and `.normal` (or `.active`) classes.

https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

**Side note**:

You could probably do away with the `.normal` class and just add those styles directly to `.left-nav` since `background` will be overridden with `&.active` and `&:hover`.

You could also combine those 2 selectors if the styles will be the same:

```
&.active, &:hover {
  background: #f68b1f;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 21px, #f68b1f 0);
}
```

Finally, I'd probably suggest moving those styles to be applied to the `<a>` (vs. having a child `<div>`) if possible.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but I still can't get it to work. Check my edit for the details.

Comment: Your code output seems to work, try here: https://jsfiddle.net/v2dcuq75/8/ - maybe something else is overwriting style?

Comment: @Osuwariboy, I also updated the above to call out that you could combine those 2 selectors.

Comment: Ok, so apparently, moving the classes to the `<a>` tag solved my problem. I also combined the two selectors together as suggested and things started working as expected. Thanks for your assistance :)